# multidimensional numpy array images

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional numpy array A, which has size (162, 254, 3). My question is how to get all the values along the third dimension?  For instance, if A is a matrix, which has a size 162*254*3, I would like to get its intensity value into one single array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
A[:,:,0]
```

That will give you the subarray where the third index is equal to zero.  The `:` gives you a slice which contains all of the indices in that dimension.

You can also get partial slices like this:

```
A[0:4,:,0]
```

Comment: I found that A[0:,:,2] is the answer that I need. Thanks a lot though.